# Importing sdk 3.0 in Eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to import Android 3.0 SDK in Eclipse but in target i can only see options for 1.5 to 2.2. What is the solution for this? I want all target from 1.5 to 3.0

Comment: Try updating to 2.2 and then to 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your eclipse go to windows->android sdk and avd manager from there left side pane show you available packages in that check on **android repository**,it will show you available packages and in that android 3.0 sdk package is available you can download that plugin and do what you want in 3.0. Hope this will help ypu

Comment: i having the android 2.3 but in virtual device list the 2.3 comes with negative tickmark.